# Find the position of all the prime numbers up to a given number

Tags: procedural-programming, prime-numbers

I want Mathematica code the does what the following pseudocode does.

```
s = 0
for i = 1 to x
  if i is a prime number then 
    s = s + 1, print s 
  else  
    print "unspecified"
```

I tried

```
numPrime1[n_] :=  
 Block[{i, j, g, s, f}, s = 0; f = 0; g = 0; 
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,               
    For[j = 1, j <= i, j++,
      If[OddQ[i/j], f = f + 1]
      ]
     If[f == 2, s = s + 1, break]               
     If[OddQ[n/i], g = g + 1;]
    ]
   If[g == 2, Print[s], Print["Ungültig"];]]
numPrime1[17]
```

Now that just returns `Null^3`

#### Edit 1

Now it returns 1, but I don't know why it shouldn't be 1. Can someone give me advice to make that work?

#### Edit 2

Solved it now this way

```
numPrime1[n_] := Block[{i, j, g, s, f}, s = 0; f = 0; g = 0;
  For[i = 1, i <= n, i++,
   For[j = 1, j <= i, j++,
     If[IntegerQ[i/j], f = f + 1];] 
    If[f == 2, s = s + 1]; 
   If[IntegerQ[n/i], g = g + 1];
   f = 0]; 
  If[g == 2, Print[s], Print["Ungültig"]];]
numPrime1[17]
```

All my tests are now correct.

Comment: It appears you are after `PrimePi`. Check details in documentation.

Comment: I want to calculate it this way so i don't have to use that

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica has a lot of prime functionality built in.  In particular `PrimeQ[x]` gives True if x is prime and false otherwise, and `PrimePi[x]` counts the number of primes less than or equal to x.

So, it seems like you want something like

```
numPrime[n_] := If[PrimeQ[n], PrimePi[n], Null]
```

so that `numPrime[17]=7` and `numPrime[21]` is Null (or you could print something, throw an error, etc.)